# Solution for DuplicateKey: E11000 duplicate key error index with Play! 2.0 Framework

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I am using the play-salat plugin with an app I am making with Play! 2.0 scala.

I get the Duplicate Key error, and the compiler points here to the error:

```
object Post extends ModelCompanion[Post, ObjectId]
```

I have read that this can be fixed in PHP [here](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/mongocursorexception-e11000) doing an unset, please tell me how to do this with Play.

I am able to post in my database the once, when I try again I get the error.

```
def save = Action { implicit request =>
postForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
  formWithErrors => BadRequest(html.newpost(formWithErrors)),
  post => {
    Post.insert(post)
    Home
  }
)
}

val postForm = Form(
mapping(
  "_id" -> ignored(new ObjectId()),
  "title" -> nonEmptyText,
  "content" -> nonEmptyText,
  "posted" -> date("yyyy-MM-dd"),
  "modified" -> optional(date("yyyy-MM-dd")),
  "tags" -> nonEmptyText,
  "categories" -> nonEmptyText,
  "userId" -> nonEmptyText
)(Post.apply)(Post.unapply)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue on my own. I am pretty new to Scala and the Play Framework.

I changed my Application.scala file like this:

```
def newpost = Action {
Ok(views.html.newpost(postForm))
}

def save = Action { implicit request =>
postForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
  formWithErrors => BadRequest(html.newpost(formWithErrors)),
  post => {
    Post.create(post.title, post.content, post.posted, post.modified, post.categories, post.tags, post.author)
    Home.flashing("success" -> "Post %s has been created".format(post.title))
  }
)
}

val postForm = Form(
mapping(
  "_id" -> ignored(new ObjectId()),
  "title" -> nonEmptyText,
  "content" -> nonEmptyText,
  "posted" -> date("yyyy-MM-dd"),
  "modified" -> optional(date("yyyy-MM-dd")),
  "categories" -> nonEmptyText,
  "tags" -> nonEmptyText,
  "author" -> nonEmptyText
)(Post.apply)(Post.unapply)
)
```

I also changed my Post.scala file:

```
 object PostDAO extends SalatDAO[Post, ObjectId](
collection = MongoConnection()("blog")("posts"))

 object Post {

  def create(title: String, content: String, posted: Date = new Date(), modified: Option[Date] = None, categories: String, tags: String, author: String) {
    PostDAO.insert(Post(
        title = title,
        content = content,
        posted = posted,
        modified = modified,
        categories = categories,
        tags = tags,
        author = author
        ))
  }

  def delete(id: String) {
    PostDAO.remove(MongoDBObject("_id" -> new ObjectId(id)))
}
}
```